# How to install Ruby 2.0.0 in kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux, ruby

Currently i have version 1.9 of Ruby installed. I need to install arachni we scanner which requires version 2.0.0. or later.
How can i upgrade it to v 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a compatible ruby in your package repo you can always install from source. It's not hard, but it does take some time to compile.

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/

Just download it and build it.

If you want to run 1.9 and 2.0 along side each other look at RVM.

https://rvm.io/

Keep in mind that some system tools may require Ruby 1.9 so rvm may be a safer option.

To use RVM you install it, then you issue a command like rvm use 2.0.0 and follow the instructions. It will download and install different ruby versions for you.